# Powershell active directory properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to find the properties of active directory:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() 

foreach ($objResult in $colResults){   
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties
```

I can call $objitem.name, but I don't know which other properties I have accessible.

How can I find which properties I can access from $objitem?

edit:

Used this solution using the answers below:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults){   
   ($colResults)[0].Properties.PropertyNames
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults){   
    $objResult.Properties | % {$_.propertynames}
}
```

should display the keys of each result property.

Comment: This will be faster: `($colResults)[0].Properties.PropertyNames`

Comment: Works like a charm. And it seems faster with Jason's bit. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get-member` (aliased as `gm`) cmdlet to get all the properties and methods. Like so,

`$objItem | gm`

Another a way is to pipe the object to `format-list` (aliased as `fl`) cmdlet, which won't list methods. Like so,

`$objItem | fl *`

Comment: Thank you for the reply anonymous. Doing that I don't get the "name", "telephonenumber", etc. And these are the ones that I want to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, preceding answers are "Powershell" features. If you really want to know what are the attributes you can reach for a given class (clas *user* here) you have to have a look to the Schema. which is avaible on Windows server registering the *schmmgmt.dll* COM object.

```
C:\>regsvr32 c:\WINDOWS\system32\schmmgmt.dll
```

JP

Comment: PowerShell features that let you get the answer.  Plus, my system certainly doesn't have schmmgmt.dll, so the PowerShell solution has fewer dependencies.

Comment: Ok, but what happens for attributes that are not valued for a given object ? And you can have a look to the schema with ADSIEDIT.MSC. if you have no administrative tools installed on your computer.