# Get user details from SharePoint with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm using this PowerShell script to get site owners:

```
$siteUrl = Read-Host "enter site url here:"

$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)

$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)

{

    foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)

    {

        Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"

    }

    $site.Dispose()
}

$rootSite.Dispose()
```

I want that it will print some details of the site owner like phone number and email. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices I think. Access the `SPUser` properties or get information from active directory.

In the first case, are you not able to access the properties as you did for `DisplayName`? I mean if you have a `SPUser` object to get the email just use:

```
 write-output "$($siteAdmin.Email)"
```

For information about to get the user properties from active directory, you can easily implement the solution provided in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594334/powershell-active-directory-properties/5597119#5597119). It worked fine for me.

Hope this helps

---

EDIT with improvement

Standing from MS Documentation you have some properties avaialble, see [SPUSer Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_members.aspx). FOr example you have not `phone`.

To get something from the active directory try to change the following function so that it returns the attributes you need (tested on windows 2k8 server):

```
function Get-AD-Data {
    $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User))"
    $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
    $objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
    $objSearcher.FindAll() | select @{L="User";E={$_.properties.displayname}},
    @{L="Department";E={$_.properties.department}},
    @{L="MemberOf";E={$_.properties.memberof}}    
}
```

This function returns all users from AD along with the selected attributes. To get information from a specific user you would use (I guess):

```
$ad_userdetails = Get-AD-Data | ? {$_.user -eq $siteAdmin.Name}
```

Cheers

Comment: nice ! tnx ! and what about the phone ?

Comment: If you'll use active directory, you have to search for the property in the AD. Check the provided link above to see how to get your AD property names.